# SQL Server converting string to numeric and sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to sort a column of strings, which contains one alphanumeric character and a numbers. If I run this:

```
select 
    column_name 
from 
    table_name 
where 
    item_type = 'ABC' 
    and item_sub_type = 'DEF' 
order by 
    cast(replace([column_name], 'A', '') as Numeric(10, 0)) desc
```

I get the correct sorted output:

```
A218
A217
A216
```

but if I try to grab the top row

```
select top 1 
    column_name 
from 
    table_name 
where 
    item_type = 'ABC' 
    and item_sub_type = 'DEF' 
order by 
    cast(replace([column_name], 'A', '') as numeric(10, 0)) desc
```

it fails with the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Any ideas on how I can select the top row?

Thanks!

Comment: if you run `select CAST(replace([item_value],'A','') AS 
Numeric(10,0))` on the entire table (remove the where clause), does it fail?

Comment: this yields the same error:  Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: I think your data has other non-numeric characters, not only 'A'. Please check it.

Comment: I believe there is some issue with you data.. Please verify your data... I am able to successfully execute the query you have provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the problem with your data - not all are match your pattern.
You can check what is not valid using:

```
select column_name from table_name where ISNUMERIC(replace([column_name],'A','')) = 0
```

Comment: And what if a value is `A$1234`... what would you expect your query to return? False (0) or True (1)?

Comment: Probably false.  The values will all be in the format A123.  The first query is sorting them correctly, but I can't figure out how to grab the top row.

Comment: @DanielHolly Spoiler alert, it returns True. Don't use ISNUMERIC to determine if something can be an integer or decimal. It's partially "broken" but isn't designed for this.

Comment: This value will be in the results set as  its not convertible to numeric(10,0)

Comment: First, your where clause is missing an operator. It needs an = 0 or =1 since `ISNUMERIC()` returns an INT... 1 for true and 0 for false. With that being said, `SELECT ISNUMERIC(replace('A$1234','A',''))` returns 1, which is true... yet isn't able to be converted to a `NUMERIC` datatype.

Comment: First, your where clause is missing an operator. It needs an = 0 or =1 since ISNUMERIC() returns an INT... 1 for true and 0 for false. - sorry miss this while copying.

Comment: One more my mistake "SELECT ISNUMERIC(replace('A$1234','A','')) returns 1" but B$1 is 0. What had I miss, do you have any links to read ?

Comment: Well B$1 returns 0 because it has a B in it... you are replacing the letter A. It's the $ that you need to look at along with commas and all sorts of special characters. 1e4 is another... since it's scientific notion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144974/discussion-between-alex-lyalka-and-scsimon).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the optimizer not executing your query how you would hope. What I mean is SQL is a declarative language--your query merely states **what** you are trying to accomplish, not **how** you are trying to accomplish it (in most cases). Thus, the optimizer determines the best way and in cases as yours, does things in certain order that causes errors. Try and force your logic with a CTE.

```
with cte as(
select column_name, [item_value] 
from table_name 
where item_type='ABC' and item_sub_type='DEF')

select top 1 column_name
from cte 
ORDER BY CAST(replace([item_value],'A','') AS Numeric(10,0)) desc
```

**SQL Server 2012/2016**

```
select top 1 column_name 
from table_name 
where item_type='ABC' and item_sub_type='DEF' 
order by TRY_CONVERT(Numeric(10,0),replace([column_name],'A','')) desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not sort them numerically...the output:  `A157
A196
A88
A174`

Comment: @DanielHolly can you show some data? Here's a test to prove it http://rextester.com/CAC60473

Answer (score 0):

Order by dropping the prefix and casting to int, provided that the prefix is the only non-numeric the rest should be pure numbers.

```
select 
    column_name 
from 
    table_name 
where 
    item_type = 'ABC' 
    and item_sub_type = 'DEF' 
order by 
    cast(replace([column_name], 'A', '') as Int) desc
```

the script above should just work, i reckon there is something wrong with your data could multiple values...

see example below

```
declare @mytable table
(
code varchar(10) 
)

insert into @mytable
values 
('A323'),
('A223'),
('A123'),
('A553'),
('A923'),
('A23'),
('A235')



select 
    code
from 
    @mytable 
order by 
    cast(replace(code, 'A', '') as Int) desc


code
----------
A923
A553
A323
A235
A223
A123
A23
```

Comment: output:  __Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A157' to data type int.__

Comment: Can you post your data please.. i think you got multiple values there

Comment: This is what the column looks like: `A218
A217
A216
A215
A214
A213
A212
A211
A210
A209
A208
A207
A206
A205
A203
A201
A200
A199
A198
A197
A196
A195
A194
A193
A192
A191
A190
A189
A188
A187
A186
A184
A182
A180
A178
A177
A176
A175
A174
A173
A172
A171
A169
A168
A167
A166
A165
A164
A163
A162
A160
A159
A158
A157
A154
A153
A152
A151
A150
A147
A145
A144
A143
A142
A141
A140
A139
A138
A136
A135
A134
A132
A131
A127
A125
A122
A119
A118
A117
A116
A114
A113
A110
A109
A108
A105
A104
A103
A102
A100
A99
A98
A96
A95`

Comment: Had to cut it off because was too long.  It goes down to A01.

Comment: What happens if you display the casted column and remove the order by?